# R: Functions -- Display of environment name instead of memory address of that environment?

Tags: r

What is the way to display the name of the environment inside the function as like built-in functions? For example, when I type the function: mean available in base package, I can see the environment as "namespace:base".

```
mean

   function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("mean")
   <bytecode: 0x0547f17c>
   **<environment: namespace:base>**
```

However, when I attach a function to the newly created environment, here to access the values for the free variable (z) inside the function (f), it automatically resides in .GlobalEnv environment and the name of the environment is not displayed inside the function, but the memory address "0x051abd60" of (e1) environment is seen.

```
     e1 <- new.env()
     e1$z <- 10
     f <- function(x) {
           x + z 
      }
     environment(f) = e1
     f

               function(x) {
                    x + z 
               }
               **<environment: 0x051abd60>**
```

Why do I see this behavior? Why don't I get my environment name inside the function as like built-in functions of R and also the functions available from various R packages? Is there a difference between environment data structure and .GlobalEnv environment available from search()

Any pointers towards the motivation behind this behavior would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the recenty released package [envnames](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/envnames) that I developed precisely as a workaround to this problem.

In your example, if you use the [environment_name()](https://rdrr.io/cran/envnames/man/environment_name.html) function of the package to retrieve the environment of function `f()` you would get `"e1"`, instead of `""` that you get using the built-in function `environmentName()`, that is:

```
library(envnames)
e1 <- new.env()
e1$z <- 10
f <- function(x) {
   x + z 
}
environment(f) = e1
environment_name(environment(f))
```

and the output is:

```
[1] "e1"
```

In the example given by Hadley where many environments point to the same environment you get ALL those environment names in a named array:

```
library(envnames)
e1 <- new.env()
e1$z <- 10
e2 <- e1
e3 <- e1

f <- function(x) {
  x + z 
}
environment(f) <- e1
environment_name(environment(f))
```

where the output includes the location of each environment as the names attribute of the returned array:

```
R_GlobalEnv R_GlobalEnv R_GlobalEnv 
       "e1"        "e2"        "e3"
```

Finally, since you mention that *seeing the memory address of the environment doesn't tell us much* about the user-defined environment we are talking about, you could **use the memory address as input argument to the `environment_name()` function to get the name of the environment (or environments) that is associated to the memory address**.

The following snippet of code and output illustrates this (where the code was run on *your* example of one single environment):

```
> f
function(x) {
       x + z 
    }
<environment: 0x0000000013f15870>
> environment_name("<environment: 0x0000000013f15870>")
[1] "e1"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set an environment name using `attr`, like so:

```
e <- new.env()
attr(e, "name") <- "xyzzy"

environmentName(e)
## [1] "xyzzy"
```

Comment: this wasn't what I what I was looking for but it was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 5):

If I recall correctly, environment names for packages and namespaces are assigned at the C level. So user-created environments do not reveal names. You cannot set an environment name in R even though there is a (misleadingly named) base function called `environmentName()`. It will only return the name assigned at C level. It is really only meant for packages and namespaces, not other environments.

Comment: I tried to add a name to the environment using the environmentName(e1) <- "e1" , but got an error like "could not find function environmentName...". Also, each environment has unique profile for them. I haven't worked with packages yet, but it is interesting to know the behavior of namespaces applied to variables and its data structures in R

Comment: have you guessed any purpose for environmentName() function?

Comment: This is mostly wrong, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

Most environments don't have names - the name of an environment is a special attribute of the environment, not the name of the object pointing to that environment.  E.g. in the following case, what would you expect the "name" of the environment of f to be?

```
e1 <- new.env()
e1$z <- 10
e2 <- e1
e3 <- e1

f <- function(x) {
  x + z 
}
environment(f) <- e1

identical(e1, e2)
identical(e1, e3)
```

Comment: There is no name for the environment of f, but the pointer  to e1 or e2 or e3 is given to it.

Comment: My understanding with environments is that there are some environments have "special attribute of name" to it. For example: Builtin environments comes with a name, but user defined environments does not allow adding a name special attribute to it. Although, I don't see any specific usage of having this special attribute to the user defined environments as the environments are linked to other objects with their object name and internally a pointer is assigned to interact between the environment and its assigned object.

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments (not reading C code) `environmentName()` does 2 things :

- first check if your environment has a `.__NAMESPACE__.$spec["name"]` where `.__NAMESPACE__.` is an environment and `spec` is a named character vector (that btw makes your environment a namespace).
- if not found falls back on `attr(, "name")`

However setting `attr(, "name")` doesn't affect the way a function is printed.

```r
# initiate
e <- new.env()
fun <- function() {}
environment(fun) <- e
e
#> <environment: 0x14b28d3a0>
fun
#> function() {}
#> <environment: 0x14b28d3a0>

# set attr(, "name") : environmentName() is changed, function still prints the same
attr(e, "name") <- "NAME1"
environmentName(e)
#> [1] "NAME1"
e
#> <environment: 0x14b28d3a0>
#> attr(,"name")
#> [1] "NAME1"
fun
#> function() {}
#> <environment: 0x14b28d3a0>

# Make it a "minimal" namespace with a name, new name takes precedence, function prints differently
e[[".__NAMESPACE__."]] <- as.environment(list(spec = c(name = "NAME2")))
isNamespace(e) 
#> [1] TRUE
environmentName(e)
#> [1] "NAME2"
e
#> <environment: namespace:NAME2>
#> attr(,"name")
#> [1] "NAME1"
fun
#> function() {}
#> <environment: namespace:NAME2>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Once you have a namespace you can change its name with `setNamespaceInfo()`

```
setNamespaceInfo("stats", "spec", c(name = "FOO"))
asNamespace("stats")
#> <environment: namespace:FOO>
``
```